# How to pass data from my script to my local server, based on Flask

Tags: python, flask

We have
1) script sends many dicts

```
my_data = ({'key1':['test1', 'test2', ['test3', 23]]})
r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/', data = my_data)
```

2) server

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def server_main():
    data = request.form.to_dict(flat=False) #this works, but with some issues, if dict.values() has lists 
data = # your ideas?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms don't handle lists well.
Try using JSON instead

Requests sends data as json if you pass it as parameter "json" instead of "data":

```
my_data = ({'key1':['test1', 'test2', ['test3', 23]]})
r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/', json = my_data)
```

Flask can parse JSON requests like this:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def server_main():
    data = request.get_json()
```

Comment: Thx, it works! But now I see code 400 Bad Request (Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0))